# filter a file with other file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris, sh

i Have a file with numbers, for example:

```
$cat file
31038467
32048169
33058564
34088662
35093964
31018168
31138061
31208369
31538163
31798862
```

and other for example with

```
$cat file2

31208369
33058564
34088662
31538163
31038467
```

Then i need other file with lines that are in the first file but not in the second

```
cat $output
35093964
31018168
31138061
31798862
32048169
```

My real file has 12'000.0000 of lines.

Then how can i do it?

Answer (score 11):

Is

```
grep -f file2 -v -F -x file1
```

sufficient?

NOTE1: Please specify in question, if the actual question is that, you need it to be time/memory optimized.

NOTE2: Get rid of any blank lines in file2.

Comment: I would only add `-F` to parse `file2` as fixed strings instead of regexps.

Comment: An important caveat: this will also partially matched lines. If `file2` contains `foo` and `file1` contains `foobar`, then that line will be filtered. This may not be intended.